# Mayavi: What does the scale_mode 'vector' do?

Tags: python, mayavi

Can someone tell me what Mayavi's `scale_mode = 'vector'` is used for?

The various plotting functions all have the same sentence in their doc string:

> scale_mode:   the scaling mode for the glyphs (‘vector’, ‘scalar’, or
>   ‘none’).

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

o = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
d = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])

mesh = mlab.quiver3d(o[0], o[1], o[2], d[0], d[1], d[2], scalars=2,
                                                         scale_mode='vector',
                                                         scale_factor=1.0)


mlab.axes(None, extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1])
mlab.gcf().scene.parallel_projection = True
mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale mode in mayavi is passed directly to vtk, which may explain the difficulty to find documentation.

In VTK, the option is passed down to a "glyph" (that is an object that is represented graphically), see the file [vtkGlyph3D.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/897333f931a4f2813b0be37ec8cf6ad919e629d9/Filters/Core/vtkGlyph3D.cxx#L475). For the mode "scale_by_vector", the magnitude of the vector data (only available for vector fields by default) is used to scale the glyph.

Note that the scaling in mayavi is done with a reference unit that depends on your data (see the [Mayavi documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#points3d)) unless the `scale_factor` option is given.

Comment: I also got a similar answer from a Mayavi developer: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/529

Comment: Ok, thanks for accepting anyway and I'm glad that I agree with Prabhu Ramachandran :-)